# How to discard hand written text while reading scanned pdf using python

Tags: python, pdf, tesseract

I am working on a problem to read scanned pdf. It has few hand written text. All I want is to get *only* printed text.
However when I am trying to read using `pytesseract` it also read hand written text which I don't want.

Comment: first detect and remove the handwritten text and then start OCR-stage

Comment: [Show us](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) an example PDF and the python code you used to process it.

Comment: @K J one could start by, manually:(, selecting ROIs containing handwritten text and  "mask" it... and if you are lucky replicate through a template (just guessing)